# How to automatically reload updated SSL certificates in Node.js Application

Tags: node.js, express, lets-encrypt

I created nodejs application and I'm using `Lets Encrypt` SSL certificates. Following is my Code

```
var express = require(‘express’);
var https = require(‘https’);
var fs = require(‘fs’);
var option = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(‘/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem’),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(‘/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem’)
};
const app = express();
app.use((req, res) =>
{
    res.end(‘Hello World’);
});

https.createServer(option, app).listen(8000);
```

I have used pm2 to start this application using following command

`sudo pm2 start app.js --watch`

I am updating SSL certificates by using following cronjob

`0 8 * * *      sudo certbot renew`

I want to reload SSL certificates automatically whenever certbot renews SSL certificates. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the flag `--post-hook` to restart your application after every renewal.

```sh
certbot renew --post-hook "pm2 restart app_name"
```

###### Update #1

Please note that the command we are running is in crontab and any global program has to be referenced with the full path. You can use the [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) command to find the executable file path for the command.

Comment: I get this error: ```Unable to find post-hook command pm2 in the PATH.``` and it's correct PM2 is not in the PATH, but that doesn't mean it's not a command available globally. I don't know if this error prevents the hook from being executed or not

Comment: @fermmm Can you please share how your pm2 is globally available? The global availability of a program is generally handled by user profile(by setting PATH in .bashrc or a similar file). Cron doesn't use any user profile and uses a clean environment for which we have to provide the full path of the program we want to use in it.

Comment: Ref 1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298775/cron-and-command-not-found. Ref 2, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384713/script-in-cron-cannot-find-command

Comment: This worked for me (replace USER 2 times with your user): `certbot renew --pre-hook "sudo -u USER bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; pm2 stop app_name'" --post-hook "sudo -u USER bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; pm2 start app_name'"` see this: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/8885 So the answer doesn't work and should be edited

Comment: @fermmm The answer has been written in a generic way so users would know about post-hook and not wirtten for copy-pasting. What you are using is a workaround and not a recommended solution because you have created a tightly coupled solution with the user profile, if someone changes config in the user profile or the profile gets deleted your cron job will also get affected. The correct solution is to directly reference the program in the command or write a new executable file.

Comment: Are we required to write sudo pm2 restart app_name?

Answer (score 14):

For those of us who can't afford to or would rather not restart our servers to reload certs and that aren't comfortable with **Dylan Landry**'s SNI-based approach, there has been a purpose-built way of doing this built into node for a while now, via `server.setSecureContext` (where server is a standard node `https` server instance). See snippet below:

```
const app = express();

function readCertsSync() {
    return {
        key: fs.readFileSync(sslKeyPath),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(sslCertPath) + fs.readFileSync(sslFullChainPath)
    }
}

let httpd = https.createServer(readCertsSync(), app).listen(port, onReady);

// Refresh httpd's certs when certs change on disk. The timeout stuff 
// "ensures" that all 3 relevant files are updated, and accounts for 
// sometimes trigger-happy fs.watch.
let waitForCertAndFullChainToGetUpdatedTooTimeout;
fs.watch(sslKeyPath, () => {
    clearTimeout(waitForCertAndFullChainToGetUpdatedTooTimeout);
    waitForCertAndFullChainToGetUpdatedTooTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        httpd.setSecureContext(readCertsSync());
    }, 1000);
});
```

The `fs.watch` and timeout code is admittedly a bit clunky and can be improved using something like [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) and some more expansive logic to monitor the state of all 3 relevant files. I chose to keep things simple to focus on the interesting bit: `setSecureContext`.

For reference, see  https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_server_setsecurecontext_options

Also, credit goes to [nolimitdev](https://github.com/nolimitdev) who came up with most of [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4464#issuecomment-357975317) before `setSecureContext` was even a thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can reload the new certs without restarting your server.

According to the issue [Reload certificate files of https.createServer() without restarting node server #15115](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15115) , specifically [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15115#issuecomment-326257131) from mscdex:

> FWIW you can already do this with SNICallback():
>
> ```js
> const https = require('https');
> const tls = require('tls');
> const fs = require('fs');
> var ctx = tls.createSecureContext({
>   key: fs.readFileSync(config.sslKeyPath),
>   cert: fs.readFileSync(config.sslCrtPath)
> });
> https.createServer({
>   SNICallback: (servername, cb) => {
>     // here you can even change up the `SecureContext`
>     // based on `servername` if you want
>     cb(null, ctx);
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> With that, all you have to do is re-assign ctx and then it will get used for any future requests.

Using the example above, you just need to do `fs.readFileSync` again on the cert path from within the `SNICallback` and attach them to the `ctx` object. But, you only want to do this when you know they've just changed. You can watch the files from javascript for changes. You can use [`fs.watch()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) for that or something from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=watch).

Comment: Is this method safe?

Comment: I'm not sure about it's security vulnerabilities are, I haven't heard of any, but I don't think I'd be the first to know either.

Comment: I've another issue, when the SSL auto renews my site is unable to connect to the node-express server but the server is running. any idea to solve this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. This was an answer I found not from experience, but by doing my own googling. I suggest whipping up your own question. More information about how it's not unable to connect would be helpful, and code for your current implementation of swapping the certificate programmatically. Sorry I can't be of more help.